# Bootstrap sub-theme with responsive and off-canvas menu module

Tags: theming, 8

I've created a custom Bootstrap sub-theme and am replacing the default Bootstrap menu with the [Responsive and Off-Canvas Menu Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_menu) but seem to be running into a string of problems.

1. No matter what settings I select, the Mobile "Burger" icon is always showing on the page. I thought it would hide depending on whether the horizontal menu was being shown or not by default. I know I can manually hide this with media queries in my CSS but just not sure if that's the optimal method.
2. I have no idea where the Off-Canvas portion of my menu is coming from? There doesn't seem to be a twig template for it. How is this being generated?
3. Also, when the off-canvas menu is being used, for some reason it's placing carats next to each link as well as the default arrow to show there is a sub-menu. Is this carat coming from the Bootstrap theme template files? Also, when I click to view the sub-menu items in the off-canvas view, none of the sub-menu items are listed at all like they are on the default horizontal view. Why is this? The off-canvas menu doesn't seem to be able to locate any sub links for some reason.

Has anyone used both Bootstrap and this Module together to shed some light on this for me and if there were any complications that you encountered as well, if any?

Comment: Sounds like this is better suited for the drupal.org issue queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Bootstrap menu--main.html.twig file was causing the issue. I just created a theme override for it and made it just the default Drupal menu code and all is working properly now.